# php form send email

Tags: php, forms, email, send

I know my php form works here on godaddy server:
http://thespanishlanguageacademy.net/los-angeles/learn-spanish-kids-children/kontact.html

Please test it yourself put your email address in and it will send you a copy.

I copy the same code into a different server. This server is not go daddy. I know php works on this server, but for some reason this form is not working:

http://hancockcollege.us/kontact.html

Here is the php code:

```
// if the Email_Confirmation field is empty
if(isset($_POST['Email_Confirmation']) && $_POST['Email_Confirmation'] == ''){

// put your email address here scott.langley.ngfa@statefarm.com, slangleys@yahoo.com
$youremail = 'bomandty@gmail.com';

// prepare a "pretty" version of the message
$body .= "Thank You for contacting us! We will get back with you soon.";
$body .= "\n";
$body .= "\n";
foreach ($_POST as $Field=>$Value) { 
$body .= "$Field: $Value\n"; 
$body .= "\n";
}

$CCUser = $_POST['EmailAddress'];

// Use the submitters email if they supplied one
// (and it isn't trying to hack your form).
// Otherwise send from your email address.
if( $_POST['EmailAddress'] && !preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $_POST['EmailAddress']) ) {
  $headers = "From: $_POST[EmailAddress]";
} else {
  $headers = "From: $youremail";
}

// finally, send the message
mail($youremail, 'Form request', $body, $headers, $CCUser );

}

// otherwise, let the spammer think that they got their message through
```

Comment: If it works on one server but not the other, then it could be server specific.  However, I will note that `$headers = "From: $_POST[EmailAddress]";` should be `$headers = "From: $_POST['EmailAddress']";`.  You forgot the quotes around your key name.

Comment: this didn't work: $headers = "From: $_POST['EmailAddress']";

Comment: When you say 'it didn't work' do you mean that you are getting an error, or are you still not receiving mail??  It could still be server specific - in regards to configuration and/or spam filters.  I only say that because you claim your current code works fine on GoDaddy servers but not on the alternate server that you are having issues with.

Comment: didnt work. didnt mail. code error.

Comment: The server might not support the mail() function.

Comment: @user2343800 what error? parse error? What did PHP report?

Answer (score 0):

First,
Use this headers:

```
<?php
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 
//Fom
$headers .= "From: XXX XXXX XXXXX <xxxx@xxxx.xxx>\r\n"; 
//Reply
$headers .= "Reply-To: example@example.com\r\n"; 
//Path
$headers .= "Return-path: example@example.com\r\n"; 
//CC 
$headers .= "Cc: example@example.com\r\n"; 
//BBC
$headers .= "Bcc: example@example.com,example@example.com\r\n"; 
?>
```

Two, Read about [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) and see the next code:

And try with this:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = "mail.example.com";
//Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
$mail->Port = 25;
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "yourname@example.com";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "yourpassword";
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP test';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//Attach an image file
$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.gif');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have to initialize manually in the other server the SMTP path, i had a similar problem time ago, setting the correct SMTP fixed my problem.

```
ini_set("SMTP", "aspmx.l.google.com");
ini_set("sendmail_from", "yourmeail@yourdomain.com");
```

Comment: Thank you! 1) Where should I put this? 2) Can you provide exact full code? 3) I am only using the send to: bomandty@gmail.com as a test. 4) It will eventually go to: admissions@hancockcollege.us.

Comment: I added here and it did not work:

ini_set("SMTP", "aspmx.l.google.com");
ini_set("sendmail_from", "bomandty@gmail.com");

// if the Email_Confirmation field is empty
if(isset($_POST['Email_Confirmation']) && $_POST['Email_Confirmation'] == ''){

Comment: In my case i had to find out the correct SMTP server with my hosting staff, they for security reasons change the default one. I opened a ticket on my CPanel and they provided the correct path, the thing is you have to set the ini_set("SMTP","SMTP_PATH") on top of all the PHP scripts you want to send emails.